# ubuntu 20.04 LTS:mongod: error while loading shared libraries: libnetsnmpmibs.so.30: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: 20.04, libraries, mongodb

i was using ubuntu 18.04 LTS and mongodb-linux-x86_64-enterprise-ubuntu1604-4.2.1 it was working fine then i upgraded to ubuntu 20.04 LTS and now i am getting error when i typed the mongod command
here is the error

```
mongod: error while loading shared libraries: libnetsnmpmibs.so.30: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

i have searched the library

```
sudo find / -name libnetsnmp.so.30* and  

apt-cache search libsnmp30
```

it did not found any thing then i tried to install it via

```
sudo apt-get install libsnmp30
```

it gives

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libsnmp30 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libsnmp30' has no installation candidate
```

can anyone please guide me on this

Comment: Is bionic-security active?

Comment: how can i check that?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue and was able to fix it by removing the existing installation and installing it again https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-enterprise-on-ubuntu-tarball/ (Enterprise Edition) or https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

I assume the version compiled for Ubuntu 18.x uses libraries that are no longer available in Ubuntu 20.x

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install the additional libraries (for bionic) as documented on the mongo website...

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4 libgssapi-krb5-2 libldap-2.4-2 libwrap0 libsasl2-2 libsasl2-modules libsasl2-modules-gssapi-mit snmp openssl liblzma5
```

[Mongo Installation Guide / Ubuntu](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-enterprise-on-ubuntu-tarball/)